# Parse id into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that contains a bunch of strings. I also have a loop of cards that each has a different 'id'. When I open the modal I want id to be displayed inside the modal (I will use it to get more info later, like name, description and deadline).

This is my loop of JSON objects:

```
<div class="card-list-body">
            {% for assignment in förseningar %}
                <div class="card card-kanban" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task-modal" id="{{assignment.id}}">

                   <script>
                     $('#task-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
                     var Id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
                     console.log("aaa")
                     $(event.currentTarget).find('input[name="modal-title"]').val(Id);
                    });
                   </script>


                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="dropdown card-options">
                      <button class="btn-options" type="button" id="kanban-dropdown-button-16" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="#">Archive Card</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title" style="white-space: initial; ">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task-modal">
                          <h6 style="font-weight: 400">
                            {{assignment.type_of_assignment}} i {{assignment.course}}                              </h6>
                        </a>
                      </div>


                    <div class="card-title" style="white-space: initial; ">
                      <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task-modal">
                        <h6 style="font-weight: 600">
                          {{assignment.name}} 
                        </h6>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title" style="white-space: initial; ">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task-modal">
                          <h6 style="font-weight: 600; color: #d21b1b">
                            Försenad
                          </h6>
                        </a>
                      </div>

                      <style>
                        .hor-list {
                          list-style-type: none;
                          overflow: hidden;
                          display: block;
                          text-decoration: none;
                          padding: 0px;
                          margin-right: 5px;
                        }
                        .circle {
                          border-radius: 50%;
                          height: 30px;
                          text-align: center;
                          width: 30px;
                        }
                        .list-item {
                          float: left;
                          margin-right: 1px
                        }
                        .initials {
                        font-size: 15px;
                        font-weight: 800;
                        line-height: 1;
                        position: relative;
                        top: 3px;
                        /* 25% of parent */
                        }
                      </style>
                       <ul class="hor-list2">
                        {% for teacher in assignment.teachers.all %}
                        <li class = "list-item2">
                          <span class="step" style="background: {{teacher.userColor}};">{{teacher.user.username|first|capfirst}}</span>
                        </li>
                      {% endfor %}

                        <li class = "list-item2">
                          <p style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 15px">
                            {{assignment.teachers.count}} Lärare:
                            {% for teacher in assignment.teachers.all %}
                            {{teacher.user.username|capfirst}}
                            {% endfor %}
                          </p>
                        </li> 
                      </ul>

                      <hr>

                      <div class="card-title" style="white-space: initial; ">
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#task-modal">
                            <h6 style="font-weight: 600; color: rgb(82, 130, 202)">
                              Börja Plugga. Skapa en studieplan
                            </h6>
                          </a>
                        </div>




                  </div>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
              </div>
```

This is a piece of the modal:

```
 <div class="modal modal-task" id="task-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Create Brand Mood Boards</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close btn btn-round" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <!--end of modal head-->
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="page-header">

                <p class="lead">Assemble three distinct mood boards for client consideration</p>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

                  <button class="btn btn-round" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user-manage-modal">
                    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:42%;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between text-small">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <i class="material-icons">playlist_add_check</i>
                      <span>3/7</span>
                    </div>
                    <span>Due 14 days</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#task" role="tab" aria-controls="task" aria-selected="true">Task</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#files" role="tab" aria-controls="files" aria-selected="false">Files</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="task" role="tabpanel">
                  <div class="content-list" data-filter-list="checklist">
```

the javascript:

```
<script>
                 $('#task-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
                 var Id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
                 console.log("aaa")
                 $(event.currentTarget).find('input[name="modal-title"]').val(Id);
                });
               </script>
```

As I said. I want a detail page of a card. So when I press the card I get a popup. I want that popup to contain a more detailed page of the card. I can't figure out how to get the data into the popup modal tho (task-modal) I think this is close but if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a little bit of advice for debugging. Whenever you face problem like this, minimize your code by using single line of data without the need of `for loop`. If possible, use direct text to replace all those `Ids` in `<tag>` to check if the code is working properly by itself with only required Bootstrap script. If the problem persists, ppl can debug your code directly through code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Three issues:

- Your javascript is inside the for loop (`{% for assignment in förseningar %}`), it should be outside. Otherwise it's repeated x times.
- `var Id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id')` means that the button triggering the modal has a `data-id` attribute. But yours doesn't, it has an `id` attribute. So either set `data-id="{{ assignment.id }}"` in the `<div class="card card-kanban" ...>` or change to `var Id = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('id')`.
- `$(event.currentTarget).find('input[name="modal-title"]')` means you're looking for an `<input name="modal-title">` element in your modal, but I don't see that anywhere. Maybe it got cut-off in which case no issue. But if you're trying to change the `modal-title` div of your modal, then the selector should be: `$(this).find('.modal-title')`.

Note: I use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.currentTarget)`. Shouldn't make any difference as the `currentTarget` is the modal and so is `this`.

Comment: I made the changes but it still didn't change.  <script>
                $('#task-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
                var Id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
                $(this).find('.modal-title').val(Id)
               });
              </script>

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint inside the function. Check the value of Id. Check the value of this. Use the console to manually reproduce the code and check the results are what you expect.

Comment: Sorry but I've never used the debugger before. Can you guess what the problem may be?

Comment: No I can't guess. If you made all the changes I suggested (i.e. also set `data-id="..."` instead of `id="..."`) it should work. The only way to figure out what else could be wrong is using the debugger. If want to program, you **have to learn to use the debugger**, it's the fastest way to figure out what a problem is. I never fix an issue just by looking at my code, I always set a breakpoint and inspect the variables to see why my code doesn't behave the way I expect.